# How can I make buttons in a for loop with a lamda expression for each?

Tags: java, javafx, local-variables

I'm trying to make a hangman game in javafx. So naturally, instead of making 26 individual buttons, I am trying to use a for loop to create each button. I am putting them into an ArrayList called alphabet and adding them to a flowPane. The trouble I am running into is when I try to set the action of each button to go to a function with the parameter of it's letter that checks to see if the letter has been used or if it is in the word.

All the instantiations:

```java
ArrayList<Button> alphabet = new ArrayList<Button>();
FlowPane keyboard = new FlowPane();
```

letterGuess function (currently empty)

```
public void letterGuess(char letter) {

}
```

The code in my launch() function:

```
char letter;
for(int i=0 ; i<26 ; i++) {
    letter = (char) (i+65);
    alphabet.add(new Button("" + letter));
    keyboard.getChildren().add(alphabet.get(i));
    alphabet.get(i).setOnAction(e -> letterGuess(letter));
}
```

I expect the code to run through without an error and successfully pass letter to letterGuess() for each button. The error I get is at letter in 
alphabet.get(i).setOnAction(e -> letterGuess(**letter**));   The error says: **Local variable letter defined in an enclosing scope must be final or effectively final**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that you're declaring `letter` outside the loop and thus trying to change it's value inside the loop. This means the lambda can't use it since it isn't a final or "effectively" final.

You can solve this by declaring the `char` as new within the loop.

Here is another way you could write the loop which will work fine:

```
    for (int i = 0; i < 26; i++) {
        char letter = (char) (i + 65);
        Button button = new Button(String.valueOf(letter));
        button.setOnAction(event -> letterGuess(letter));
        alphabet.add(button);
    }
```

---

You could also declare `letter` as `final` within the loop, but it is not necessary in this case. Because `letter` is only assigned a value once in the loop, it is *effectively* `final` and the lamba knows it.

Answer (score 0):

`variables` used in `lambda` must be `global` , `final` or `effectively final` for its proper execution. so you can make it final as it is local in loop :

`final char letter = (char) (i+65);`

**OR**

Declare `letter` as global variable.

Answer (score 0):

Working code looks like:

```java
for(int i=0; i<26 ; i++) {
    char letter = (char) (i+65);
    alphabet.add(new Button("" + letter));
    keyboard.getChildren().add(alphabet.get(i));
    alphabet.get(i).setOnAction(e -> letterGuess(letter));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
List alphabets = IntStream.range(0, 26)
            .mapToObj(i -> (char) (i + 65))
            .map(l -> new Button(String.valueOf(l)))
            .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

You can do it in a single line forgive me for the syntax error if you have coz I am typing it from my mobile.